# Can't type in Terminal during SSH session after CTRL+C Mac OSX

Tags: mac, ssh

I have a very strange problem. Here is what happens:

- I log into one of my machines via SSH (server is Mac OS 10.5)
- I start a program and while it is running I type (CTRL+C) to quit it (i.e. tail -f)
- Afterward I cannot see ANYTHING I type
- I can type commands (without seeing them) and execute them and see the output.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get a prompt (i.e. `PS1`) when this happens? Or no prompt either? What happens when you press `^C` repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, I do get a prompt. Also, I can change the prompt and the PS1 is fine. When I press ^C repeatedly nothing changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try typing "reset" in the terminal to reset the terminal settings.

Sounds like your stdout is getting redirected somewhere other then your pty.

Comment: In some cases, you might have to press Ctrl-j before and after (and type `reset` blindly).

Answer (score 0):

As Kyle suggested, try to reset your terminal window - I´d suggest using the shortcut "cmd + R" for that though, assuming the computer from that your ssh´ing in is also a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't type in the terminal after I connected to the ssh. But I fixed it just by adding a new terminal at the right upper corner of the terminal in my VS Code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).